# New missing/unsatisfied dependencies: service jboss.jdbc-driver.com_mysql (missing) dependents: [service jboss.data-source.java:jboss/MyDB]

Tags: java, jboss

I am using JBoss 7.1.1. When I try to start the server, I get an exception. I have tried many solutions but nothing seems to work.

The following line appears in the logs -

`New missing/unsatisfied dependencies:
      service jboss.jdbc-driver.com_mysql (missing) dependents: [service jboss.data-source.java:jboss/MyDB]`

Here is my standalone.xml:

```
</datasource>
    <datasource jta="true" jndi-name="java:jboss/MyDB" pool-name="MyDB_Pool" enabled="true" use-java-context="true" use-ccm="true">
        <connection-url>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test</connection-url>
        <driver>com.mysql</driver>
        <security>
            <user-name>root</user-name>
            <password>root</password>
        </security>
        <timeout>
            <idle-timeout-minutes>0</idle-timeout-minutes>
            <query-timeout>600</query-timeout>
        </timeout>
        <statement>
            <prepared-statement-cache-size>100</prepared-statement-cache-size>
            <share-prepared-statements>true</share-prepared-statements>
        </statement>
    </datasource>
    <drivers>
        <driver name="h2" module="com.h2database.h2">
            <xa-datasource-class>org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcDataSource</xa-datasource-class>
        </driver>
        <driver name="com.mysql" module="com.mysql">
            <xa-datasource-class>com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlXADataSource</xa-datasource-class>
        </driver>
    </drivers>
</datasources>
```

This is my module.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.1" name="com.mysql">
<resources>
    <resource-root path="mysql-connector-java-5.1.24-bin.jar"/>
</resources>
<dependencies>
    <module name="javax.api"/>
    <module name="javax.transaction.api"/>       
    <module name="javax.servlet.api" optional="true"/>
    <module name="javax.validation.api"/>
</dependencies>
</module>
```

But i still got this exception

Here is my web.xml(a part of it):

```
<resource-ref id="ResourceRef_1">
    <res-ref-name>MyDB</res-ref-name>        
    <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
    <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
    <res-sharing-scope>Shareable</res-sharing-scope>
    <lookup-name>java:jboss/datasources/MyDB</lookup-name>
</resource-ref>
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 3):

Your `module.xml` should be like this:

```
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.0" name="com.mysql" slot="main">
  <resources>
    <resource-root path="mysql-connector-java-5.1.24-bin.jar"/>
  </resources>
  <dependencies>
    <module name="javax.api"/>
  </dependencies>
</module>
```

And make sure you have `mysql-connector-java-5.1.24-bin.jar` and `mysql-connector-java-5.1.24-bin.jar.index` in same folder where you have `module.xml`.

Comment: same exception with this module.xml

Comment: @pulse: Having module.xml is not enough. Make sure you have valid jars in same folder as xml.

Comment: they are all in the folder org/mysql/main/jar,module.xml

Comment: @pulse:org/mysql is not correct path. In your xml, you are telling com/mysql

Comment: @pulse: you need to create mysql folder in module-->com--> folder. NOT IN ORG-->MYSQL because module.xml has entry name="com.mysql"

Comment: if i use this path in module.xml and standalone.xml it comes this exception:Error loading module from /Users/bahram/Downloads/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final/modules/com/mysql/main/module.xml

Comment: sorry it was my mistake..shure i git it in modules/com/mysql/main/jar,module.xml and now??

Comment: @pulse: AS I commented earlier, do you have mysql folder in /Users/bahram/Downloads/jboss-as-7.1.1Final/modules/com folder? If not, you need to create one there and copy your jars to that folder

Comment: @pulse: No jar, please remove jar folder, everything should be just inside main folder.

Comment: yes i got this folder..and everything is in it(jar,module.xml)

Comment: maybe its a mac os x problem...because i used several versions which i have found in the internet...but nothing works for me

Answer (score 1):

Solved: New missing/unsatisfied dependencies: service jboss.jdbc-driver.com_ for Jboss / WildFly 10

Hi,
first stop the WildFly server.
then update standalone.xml file to add MS-SQL JTDS driver details and Datasource details like below:

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:datasources:4.0">
            <datasources>
                <datasource jta="true" jndi-name="java:/jdbc/speedtest-datasource" pool-name="MSSQLDSspeedTestDEV" enabled="true" use-ccm="true">
                    <connection-url>jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://serverName:1433;DatabaseName=dbName</connection-url>
                    <driver-class>net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver</driver-class>
                    <driver>JTDS</driver>
                    <security>
                        <user-name>username</user-name>
                        <password>password</password>
                    </security>
                    <validation>
                        <valid-connection-checker class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.mssql.MSSQLValidConnectionChecker"/>
                        <background-validation>true</background-validation>
                    </validation>
                </datasource>
                <drivers>

                    <driver name="JTDS" module="net.sourceforge">
                        <driver-class>net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver</driver-class>
                    </driver>

                </drivers>
            </datasources>
        </subsystem>
```

Module.xml for MS SQL JTDS: path :  E:\Softwares\wildfly-10.1.0.Final\wildfly-10.1.0.Final\modules\system\layers\base\net\sourceforge\main  ( need to create directory structure as highlighted and add module.xml and jtds-1.3.0.jar files).

(note in this example i have used module name as "net.sourceforge" and created the folder structure path as "net\sourceforge\main"). Please note this is more important to match the directory path and module name in module,xml file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.0" name="net.sourceforge">
<resources>
<resource-root path="jtds-1.3.0.jar"/>
</resources>
<dependencies>
<module name="javax.api"/>
<module name="javax.transaction.api"/>
</dependencies>
</module>
```

Note: Please note that the path highlighted in green above at 2 places should match (ie directory structure and module name in module.xml),

For example. If  you have created directory structure as E:\Softwares\wildfly-10.1.0.Final\wildfly-10.1.0.Final\modules\system\layers\base\net\sourceforge\jtds\main  then module name in module.xml file should be “net.sourceforge.jtds” as shown below in module.xml file

```
Module.xml:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.0" name="net.sourceforge.jtds">
<resources>
<resource-root path="jtds-1.3.0.jar"/>
</resources>
<dependencies>
<module name="javax.api"/>
<module name="javax.transaction.api"/>
</dependencies>
</module>
```

now save these two files and restart the wildFLY server.

```
Regards,
Rasool Javeed Mohammad
javeed.mca@gmail.com
```

Comment: the question is how to connect to a mysql database with the mysql driver, this answer just confuses matters by bringing MS SQL and jtds into the mix, first answer I've ever down voted but it is bad

Answer (score 0):

try upgrading your mysql-connector.  i was trying to deploy 5.1.5 (i was migrating from jboss 5.1 to 7.1.1 so i was just moving an already working environment over to the newer container).  after banging my head against this for two days, i upgraded to 5.1.27 and the datasource deployed like a champ.

Answer (score 0):

Try to delete META-INF/services/java.sql.Driver from the mysql connector lib.

Answer (score 0):

One thing to check with this error is to make sure you are storing the data in the correct folder. For JBoss EAP 7.1, it is the `modules\system\layers\base\com` folder. Inside of the `com` folder, create an additional folder called `mysql` and a `main` folder inside of the `mysql` folder. The `main` folder will hold the jar file and the module.xml file.

Answer (score 0):

Try below steps. i solve the same problem with you in wildfly8.0.0-final. if there occurs that duplicate mysql dependencies, remove configuration firstly, after restart your computer, try the steps again.

#### 1. Create mysql folder

under: ${WILDFLY_HOME}/modules/system/layers/base

create the directories com/mysql/driver/main

copy the driver library jar Into the folder main

add module.xml

// urn:jboss:module:X.X should be same with the version of wildfly, you can reference other modules.

```
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.1" name="com.mysql.driver">
    <resources>
         <resource-root path="mysql-connector-java-5.1.16.jar" />
    </resources>
    <dependencies>
         <module name="javax.api"/>
         <module name="javax.transaction.api"/>
    </dependencies>
</module>
```

#### 2. Register the module as driver with CLI.

${WILDFLY_HOME}/bin/standalone.sh (only if wildfly is not running)

./jboss-cli.sh

connect

/subsystem=datasources/jdbc-driver=mysql:add(driver-name=mysql,driver-module-name=com.mysql.driver,driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver)

If the operation is successful then the message below will be showed {"outcome" => "success"}

and into the file of the standalone profile the code below is produced
...

```
<driver name="mysql" module="com.mysql.driver">
    <driver-class>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</driver-class>
</driver>
```

#### 3. Create database in mysql

login as root: mysql root -p
Create database

create tables

#### 4. Create connection to database from console

http://localhost:9990/console

add datasources with configuration like

```
name: mysql
JNDI name: java:jboss/mysql
url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/your_database
```

done.